# Strange vertical lines appearing in Emacs on OS X?

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24

My emacs is displaying strange vertical lines. These lines appear in any colour and length randomly. There doesn't seem to be any reason why they would appear. They disappear/change sometimes when I switch buffers or scroll - basically any activity that forces the entire frame to redraw. They appear in any part of the frame at random, but especially in the line number's gutter, and on both sides. I'm using Emacs 24.1 on OS X 10.7.4. I've checked, all other applications render perfectly fine, this is happening only in Emacs. I tried to find any similar problems on the web, but I couldn't find anything at all, so I thought I'd post here.

The problem is not work-stopping, but it's definitely annoying. Any help would be much appreciated.

A [screenshot](http://snag.gy/WznV4.jpg) is attached. The lines can be seen on the sides here. There are dark lines in the line numbers area and white lines on both sides. You can also see some red dotted lines in the bottom left.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920210/what-causes-this-graphical-error-in-emacs-with-linum-mode-on-os-x or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123431/cocoa-emacs-glitch-in-vertical-border-using-linum-mode to possible solutions.

Comment: Update to Emacs 24.3, or probably even a pretest or snapshot build first.  The Cocoa port of Emacs is constantly being improved, so chances are good that the specific issue is already fixed in a recent release.