# Cocoa Emacs: Glitch in vertical border using linum mode

Tags: macos, emacs

Using Cocoa Emacs on OS X 10.7, I get an irritating graphical glitch in the vertical border with linum mode enabled.

With a vertically-split frame, enable linum mode and try scrolling up and down in either side of the split. The vertical border disappears either fully or partially.

I can fix this by changing fringe-mode to left-only, but the fix ONLY works if I do it in the minibuffer. Trying to do it from lisp code (using fringe-mode, set-fringe-mode or set-fringe-style) doesn't solve the glitch (I've tried several different hooks).

I've reported this to the Emacs bug tracker, but I'd expect SO to be faster! Could anyone suggest a programmatic workaround, or shed some light on what might be going on here?

UPDATE: For some reason the command fringe-mode doesn't work from lisp code, but I was able to get a programmatic solution by doing

```
(set-fringe-mode '(8 . 0))
```

... Although it seems to have raised another graphical glitch.

Comment: Ideas to do what?  The bug is in the C code, you reported it, and you have a workaround, so I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920210/what-causes-this-graphical-error-in-emacs-with-linum-mode-on-os-x (and yes, I hate this bug too. Thanks for reporting it!)

Comment: Stefan -- apologies for being vague. I was looking for a programmatic workaround rather than having to manually set fringe-mode on every run. But also just any enlightenment on what's causing this. And I'm not certain it's in the C code - it could well be a fault in linum, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: jmdeldin - actually a slightly different glitch, but probably related.

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in Emacs trunk. Note that the solution above works to some degree for older versions.