# Horrible rendering of windows using Emacs 24 with OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: emacs, osx-mountain-lion

I installed `OS X Mountain Lion` on my laptop, and downloaded `Emacs 24` (the pre-compiled version available at [emacs for mac os x](http://emacsformacosx.com))  . The rendering of the application window, especially when I scroll fast or even sometimes slow *is just horrible*.

[image]

If anyone could suggest a solution I would be really grateful. It is bad enough to make me abandon Emacs for some other editor, if I cannot figure this out.

The nearest query I could find on Stackoverflow was [Strange vertical lines appearing in Emacs on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904035/strange-vertical-lines-appearing-in-emacs-on-os-x)

I am using Kieran Healy's Emacs Social Science Starter Kit (http://kieranhealy.org/emacs-starter-kit.html), so I haven't added my own cusomisations yet--and indeed some of the existing customisations are for his machine, not mine. But my init.el file (such that it is) is as follows:

```
;;; init.el --- Where all the magic begins
;;
;; Part of the Emacs Starter Kit
;;
;; This is the first thing to get loaded.
;;

;; org-mode windmove compatibility
(setq org-replace-disputed-keys t)

;; setq dotfiles-dir (file-name-directory (or (buffer-file-name) load-file-name)))
(setq dotfiles-dir (file-name-directory (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))))


(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name
                     "lisp" (expand-file-name
                             "org" (expand-file-name
                                    "src" dotfiles-dir))))

;; Package Locations
;; Location of various local packages (in .emacs.d/vendor or .emacs.d/src)
;;  because I don't want to keep them in =/Applications/Emacs.app/= or in
;;  =/usr/share/local/=.

(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
    (let* ((my-lisp-dir "~/.emacs.d/")
       (default-directory my-lisp-dir))
  (setq load-path (cons my-lisp-dir load-path))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)))

;; Font-face setup. Check the availability of a some default fonts, in
;; order of preference. The first of these alternatives to be found is
;; set as the default font, together with base size and fg/bg
;; colors. If none of the preferred fonts is found, nothing happens
;; and Emacs carries on with the default setup. We do this here to
;; prevent some of the irritating flickering and resizing that
;; otherwise goes on during startup. You can reorder or replace the
;; options here with the names of your preferred choices.

(defun font-existsp (font)
   "Check to see if the named FONT is available."
   (if (null (x-list-fonts font))
     nil t))

;; Set default font. First one found is selected.
(cond
 ((eq window-system nil) nil)
  ((font-existsp "PragmataPro")
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 121 :font "PragmataPro"))
 ((font-existsp "Menlo")
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 121 :font "Menlo"))
 ((font-existsp "Consolas")
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 121 :font "Consolas"))
 ((font-existsp "Inconsolata")
  (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 121 :font "Inconsolata"))
 )

;; Load up Org Mode and Babel
(require 'org-install)

;; load up the main file
(org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "starter-kit.org" dotfiles-dir))

;;; init.el ends here
```

Comment: Do you have a customized .emacs? If so, could you add that to your post? It might be some setting in the .emacs that gives emacs + mountain lion indigestion.

Comment: Your snapshot shows a clear bug, so the best thing to do is to report it with `M-x report-emas-bug`.  Hopefully this way it can be fixed for 24.3 (which is in the pretest phase).

Answer (score 2):

Try checking that you aren't setting the frame height greater than your screen height. My .emacs was set to do this from another computer with a greater vertical resolution and I saw the same behaviour as you. For me, I had this block:

```lisp
(setq default-frame-alist
      '((width . 80)
        (height . 40)
        (menu-bar-lines . 1)
        (vertical-scroll-bar . -1)))
```

and I had to reduce the height from 60 to the 40 you see here to avoid this problem.

Comment: not sure about the exact cause but I was also able to eliminate the issue by removing some code that was manipulating the window size.

Comment: Robin, that seems to do it. Thank you. I am afraid I fail to understand why. After all, the frame height was in any case much less than the screen height. Maybe I should just be happy it works, but would be happier still if I understood the reasons.

Comment: I also do not understand why. I just noticed that my original height of 60 seemed to be larger than the screen. A bit of trial and error later and I was lucky on this occasion. I agree with @Stefan that it is a bug.